# Set jQuery Tabs default position to collapsed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery Tabs which are collapsible - http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#collapsible - and would like to know how I can start with all tabs collapsed when page loads, then for a tab to be activated on mouse click?

Thank you.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Please clarify a bit.... What do you really want?

Comment: I would like all tabs to be collapsed (tab content hidden) on pageload, and then to active a tab on mouse click

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/PmsCh/1/

Just set the `active` option to `false` like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

Comment: Using this, the first tab is still activated on page load.

Comment: <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      collapsible: true,
   selected: -1
    });
  });
  </script> // its not working

Comment: 'tabs' - same as the example

Comment: @Mike - are you definitely including both jquery and jquery ui? Would you be able to add your code to your question so I can take a look?

Comment: @Mike - sorry about that, I've just updated my answer. It seems that the `selected` option was replaced with `active` in newer versions of jQuery UI.